# jQuery function inside each only returns the value from last element

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, each

I'm trying to pass html elements text values with a specific class as a parameterto a function inside an each function.

The output returns only the last text value passed.

I would like to assign each text value to the function contained within an element right next to it, so it returns the value as a parameter for the function of every different block of html code.

**jQuery code :**

```
$(".optin-holder").each(function(index,obj) {   

    $(this).html("<div class='contentOptin'>" +  new Optin($(this).next().text()) + "</div><br/><br/>");

  //$(this).html("<div class='contentOptin'>" + $(this).next().text() + "</div><br/><br/>");                                        

}); 

function Optin(promoNumber){    

var promo = promoNumber;

var content = '<input onclick="javascript:saveActivity('+promo+')"  type="button" name="logOptin" value="PARTICIPAR" class="btn btnParticipate" />';

$(".contentOptin").html(content);

}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="offerBoxAll">
    <div class="optin-holder">
        <div class="contentOptin">
            <input class="btn btnParticipate"  onclick="javascript:saveActivity(1284)" name="logOptin" value="PARTICIPAR" type="button">
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="test">1283</div>
</div>


<div class="offerBoxAll">
    <div class="optin-holder">
            <div class="contentOptin">
                <input class="btn btnParticipate" onclick="javascript:saveActivity(1284)" name="logOptin" value="PARTICIPAR" type="button">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test">1284</div>
</div>
```

As you can see it is passing just the latest value to each iteration.

I need to pass the value of the `.test` class right next to every `.contentOptin` class.

The commented line gives me the value I need for every iteration but is not inside the function as parameter. The `Optin(param)` function appends some  code which is passing the value of `.test` class text  to  `saveActivity(param)` function as a parameter within the element with `.contentOptin` class.

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/puzzledGalore/sfoams64/1/)

Comment: Can't really reproduce that -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zym4gsrp/

Comment: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/puzzledGalore/rrufmpsf/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$(this).next().text()` with `$(this).find(".test").text()`.

`$(this).find(".test").text()` will find the value of `div` having `test` class for each `optin-holder` `div`.

**Js change**

```
$(".optin-holder").each(function(index,obj) {                               
    $(this).html("<div class='contentOptin'>" + Optin($(this).find(".test").text()) + "</div><br/><br/>");
    // $(this).html("<div class='contentOptin'>" + $(this).next().text() + "</div><br/><br/>");                                     

});
```

Comment: Sorry I had mistyped the HTML code, now is the right one in which element with class .test is not a descendant from element with class .optin-holder So I can not use the find function from jQuery. Perhaps you can come up with another solution. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the element with value inside function and set a conditional statement within 'each' to check if the given value for this element is equal to the argument passed to the function. jsfiddle.net/puzzledGalore/6sy7badn/